# Making sure GUI objects get put into garbage collector

Tags: java, swing, javafx

So I was wondering, lets say I have a scene(javafx)/jpanel(swing) and I assign it to null. Would it make everything attached to it like buttons null? If not is there an easy way to make them null so memory gets free up eventually?

Comment: An object only becomes eligible to garbage collection if it's unreachable.  So for example, if you have a some kind of listener/observer registered with any of the components, which some other object has a strong reference to (say the scene), then no, setting your own references to `null` won't make them eligible for garbage collection.  You need to sever all the ties you can think of

Comment: So would it be best to set everything attached to the scene every button, label etc to null to free up the most memory? If so is there a better way to go about it than 1 line of code for every object?

Comment: It would be better to ensure that any listeners/observers you have attached to the component(s) are weak when you `null` the main component. For example, the component might setup internal listeners/observers. but so long as nothing outside of the component has a strong reference to them, then you simply set the upper reference to `null`.  It's when you have listeners/observers out side of the component when you into trouble.  You should also make sure that the component is removed cleanly from it's parent

Comment: In other words - just make sure that in your own code your services, "Listeners" or "Observers" are stateless and that you don't have any more references to the component or inner components. If you don't - just setting it to `null` will do the job. I don't think any framework listeners would keep a reference to your components, but you can always read the javadoc to make sure